# Is a sequence of only number 1 monotonic?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we have a sequence made only by numbers one, is that sequence monotonic or constant?

Because it suffices both increasing and decreasing criteria.

a(n+1)<=a(n) and reverse

Comment: It is both monotonic increasing and decreasing but not strictly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is both monotonic increasing, and monotonic decreasing, and constant. But it is not strictly increasing, and it is not strictly decreasing.